# Why isnt the move constructor called here?

Tags: c++, constructor

I am trying to understand when the move constructor is called, and wrote this simple piece of code:

```
class myClass
{
public:
    myClass(int value)
    {
        cout << "This is my constructor" << endl;
    }
    myClass(const myClass& other)
    {
        cout << "This is my copy constructor" << endl;
    }
    myClass(myClass&& other)
    {
        cout << "This is my move constructor" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    myClass a(myClass(3));
}
```

The output is:

> This is my constructor

I understand the constructor is called for myClass(3). My question is, why isn't the move (or even copy) constructor called for moving the memory to 'a'?

Comment: The compiler recognizes that it isn't needed; you create a new temporary instance with integer parameter 3, and assign it directly to a variable.  The compiler eliminated the unnecessary overhead and created a as though it was built with a parameter of 3.  The same result would be attained with myClass a = myClass(3);

Comment: Try compiling with -o0

Comment: You may find [**this page**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) interesting.